# How to add all projects to a single solution with dotnet sln?

Tags: c#, .net, projects-and-solutions, solution, dotnet-cli

Following examples from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln) I'm trying to execute

```
dotnet sln AllProjects.sln add **/*.csproj
```

But I get this error:

> Could not find project or directory `**/*.csproj`.

Looks like wildcards are not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whats the Operating System?

Comment: Windows, PowerShell

Comment: is your projects are in .net core?

Comment: No, they are not

Comment: Not 100% on this but I think the ***/* is Linux based...try just (dot)  ./* or (dot)(dot) if your backing up one level

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've missed this statement:

> Globbing patterns are supported on Unix/Linux based terminals

My Windows PowerShell solution looks like this:

```
$projects = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^.+\.(csproj|vbproj)$' }

$uniqueProjects = $projects | Group-Object -Property Name | Where Count -EQ 1 | select -ExpandProperty Group | % { $_.FullName }

Invoke-Expression -Command "dotnet new sln -n AllProjects"

$uniqueProjects | % { Invoke-Expression -Command "dotnet sln AllProjects.sln add ""$_""" }
```

Comment: This should be voted down. Way too much work. The right answer is below: dotnet sln add (ls **/*.csproj)

Comment: Official documentation contains all the solutions much better than this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln

Answer (score 29):

For Windows, open PowerShell and run this command to add all projects to the solution file:

```
 dotnet sln add (ls -r **/*.csproj)
```

Comment: How can this be done in Linux?

Comment: Running the above command throws the error: _syntax error near unexpected token `('_ because the '$' before the _ls_ is missing. The correct syntax is: _dotnet sln add $(ls -r **/*.csproj)_ which is working on (Git and Linux) bash.

Comment: dotnet sln add $(ls -r **/*.csproj)

Comment: @astef this is the correct answer. For linux/unix just use "dotnet sln add mysolution.sln **/*.csproj

Answer (score 7):

On Windows you could also use the following command to recursively add all the projects in sub-directories to a pre-existing solution file:

```
FOR /R %i IN (*.csproj) DO dotnet sln add "%i"
```

Alternatively, if you need to (re)create solution files often then you could create a batch file with the following content, and then just run it whenever you need to:

```
dotnet new sln 
FOR /R %%i IN (*.csproj) DO dotnet sln add "%%i"
```

Please note that you need the extra % when trying to do this inside the batch file.

Answer (score 4):

I tried ls -r on git bash

```
dotnet sln add (ls -r **/*.csproj)
```

but it gives me

```
$ dotnet sln add (ls -r **\*.csproj)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

And then i tried

```
dotnet sln add **/*.csproj
```

it worked for me on git bash(windows)

Comment: The simbol $ before the (ls...) is missing.

Comment: On that section i wrote command with console output and that $ sign is not from command. The command you should execute is first command or last command in this answer. Second one is output of first one

Comment: dotnet sln add $(ls -r **/*.csproj)

Answer (score 1):

For linux

```
find . -name "*.csproj" -print0 | xargs -0 dotnet sln add


find . -name "*.csproj" ! -name "exclude-this.csproj" -print0 | xargs -0 dotnet sln add
```