# Rider/JetBrains - How to run one solution file from directory tree view?

Tags: xamarin, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

Using Rider, I've "imported as a directory", a root folder that contains many different solutions/projects/folders. What I'd like to figure out is, how to build/run one of these solutions from the tree view. This is the structure of what I'm working with, and the error message I get when I try to Build:

[image: directoryTree]

...which makes sense because I'm not specifying what .sln to build because that root folder doesn't have a .sln file itself, each subfolder is what I'm looking to work with.

So how could I launch one of these solutions from this window/view? Rider offers the option of importing a folder as a directory so I would assume there's capabilities to do this? I'm trying to avoid opening new windows for each individual project re: computer resources. I'd like to just launch any of these projects from this window. Possible?

**UPDATE**

Based on comments, here are 2 of those folders expanded for more info on what's in them:

[image: ExpandedFolders]

Comment: Have you tried opening the csproj file for that specific project you want to work on?

Comment: I'm getting confused about the mixed terminology you use: does every single folder contain a `sln` file? Or only a `csproj` file? Rider works upon Solution files, not directories. If you want to work your way, you have to use `dotnet build` from Rider`s integrated terminal and/or create a run configuration for the build & debug

Comment: @Cheesebaron See the expanded tree image added above for the basic layouts of the projects

Comment: @mu88 Not sure I know what you mean, when I "open" the csproj file it just opens the IDE to that file. What I'm trying to do is run/build/emulate any one of those projects from this main window, without having to open 10 different windows for each one.

Comment: Then just create a solution with all of the projects in it.

Comment: ...Again, not sure what that means. Like, make a .sln file that contains the names of all the projects in it, and then save it in that root directory? I tried that, and I still get the same error as before, says there's no solution file, even though it IS there. I would suggest trying to throw 2 or more of your app folders into one, then import that that folder as a directory into rider, and try to run/emulate one of those projects individually.

Comment: Open Rider, click on _New Solution_ and save it. Then open this solution, it will be empty. Right-click on it and add all the existing projects. Otherwise use `dotnet sln add` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017316/how-to-add-all-projects-to-a-single-solution-with-dotnet-sln)

Comment: @mu88 I think I'm getting the hang of it. Using powershell and that dotnet command isn't working for me as I get the error `The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.` and it doesn't pull in the android or iOS projects, so I'm just doing it manually in Rider and it seems to work. Thanks!